# Login action fails intermittently

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have put up with this bug for a while but it have reached its limit of acceptance. I have a login control that works "fine". fine meaning it authenticates most often successfully but at other times i try to log in and its like i hit an invisible wall.
"Server Error in '/' Application.
Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'Selase-PC\Selase'."

i thought i could wait for couple of minutes and try again every time since it logs in successfully again after some time but that has gotten beyond acceptance. i cant wait for it any more and i cant keep waiting for it all the time so i sort to get some solution from my lovely friends around here.

It displays a very long stack trace and i so much want to show you guys what the stack trace reads but wait a minute....

> 'Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'Selase-PC\Selase'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'Selase-PC\Selase'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'Selase-PC\Selase'.]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5009598
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +183
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +239
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
>      System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) +95
>      System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +206
>      System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) +827
>      System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +105
>      System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +106
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +60
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +129
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +127
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +101
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +167
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

i hope this will do?
Counting on your responses....
Cheers

the Event log as requested by User422...

> - 
> - 1309 
>     3 
>     3 
>     0x80000000000000 
>      
>     28752 
>     Application 
>     Selase-PC
> - 3005 
>     An unhandled exception has occurred. 
>     1/20/2011 14:34:01 
>     1/20/2011 06:34:01 
>     890c153a58d84bdba72cb0163158407b 
>     23 
>     1 
>     0 
>     42af9d49-5-129399788112990000 
>     Full 
>     / 
>     C:\Users\Selase\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Prototype5\Prototype5\ 
>     SELASE-PC 
>      
>     8732 
>     WebDev.WebServer40.exe 
>     Selase-PC\Selase 
>     SqlException 
>     Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for user 'Selase-PC\Selase'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
>     http://localhost:55098/Account/Login.aspx 
>     /Account/Login.aspx 
>     127.0.0.1 
>      
>     False 
>      
>     Selase-PC\Selase 
>     12 
>     Selase-PC\Selase 
>     False 
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: where is the database? is in local or on a server somewhere? do you have control over it?

Comment: @ Djee - Local..right here on my PC...

Comment: what does the log say about the logon error? Is the db configured for a login 'Selase-PC\Selase' ?

Comment: are you are impersonating the ASP process? What is your connection string?

Comment: Is this an impersonating / delegation scenario? (single sign on in a ActiveDirectory LAN?) - or are you using a file based SQLExpress scenario, where the db lays in a local filesystem?

Comment: @User4922 -  It only tells me it failed as an un-handled exception occurred. And am not sure if i have to configure the database for log in too but all i do is connect to it and compare log in details and get the authentication.

Comment: @ Mitch - Not at all...no backups. am just running the application from my personal computer with MS SQL management studio 2008 installed.

Comment: Are you able to log in to SqlServer management studio (If using MSSQl) using the same credentials you provided in connection string

Comment: @ User492238 MS SQL Management Studio 2008

Comment: @ Shekhar - Yes..every now and then after the time out expires i guess

Comment: well then i am no sure what is wrong better recheck your connection string.. once i had my password contain an special character and it was escaped by compiler so had the same problem as yours...

Comment: @User492238 - DB resides in the local system where am running the application from. am not sure if am guessing right but i think just a file based SQL Express scenario where DB is on the local file system

Comment: please post your connection string!

Comment: please post the entry from your windows system event log protocol (Eventlog Viewer -> Application, or Security | source: your database server)

Comment: @ User492238 this is my connection string <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="CMSSQL3ConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=SELASE-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CMSSQL3;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: why are you using more than one connection string? Which one is causing problems? (which one is the one, you are using in your membership provider configuration?)

Comment: is this related to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643308/how-to-display-user-name-in-login-name-control ? You may should follow the guidelines on using SQLConnections. Try wrapping the connection in a using block, so it will properly get closed.

Comment: @USer492238 -I have updated the post and added the event log

Comment: @User492238 Am using the connection string by name "CMSSQL3ConnectionString1" and yes it is related to the post you inserted. But i have greatly made changes with that application and modified it into a different project, which is why i had to create a different connection string.

Comment: -1 for using others people effords without the will, to give anything back to the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your db filebase seems to be locked due to concurrent access. Make sure, you are using the sql connections properly. It is, disposing it off properly after use. At best wrap it in a using block.

Also consider implementing your own membership provider class, if you are using a custom authentication scheme. It also helps, getting a more clean design.